# Обновление SQL на сервере через PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите кодом в PHP, у меня есть база данных в sql на сервере, залита таблица с полями id, name и int и мне нужно чтоб скрипт проверял каждые 10 сек. таблицу и если значение int в полях было болше 3, то удалял эти поля

Comment: Нельзя удалять поля. Удаление поля - это изменение структуры таблицы. Удалить можно запись, целиком. И для этого не нужен никакой PHP-скрипт, с такой задачей легко справится планировщик MySQL (см. [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html)).

Comment: А как удалить запись в бд при помощи php?

Comment: Выполнить запрос `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE {conditions}`. Условия отбора определяют, какие записи будут удалены.

Comment: Из вашей формулировки не очень понятно. Вам надо удалять значение `int`, сохраняя `id, name` или же удалить всю строку, если значение поля больше 3?

Comment: Послность удалить запись с id, name и int

Comment: ну тогда @Akina уже ответил на ваш вопрос. Теперь не понятно, что еще тут может быть не понятно )